# Pandas read_sql_query converting integer column to float

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following line

```
df = pandas.read_sql_query(sql = sql_script, con=conn, coerce_float = False)
```

that pulls data from Postgres using a sql script. Pandas keeps setting some of the columns to type float64.  They should be just int. These columns contain some null values. Is there a ways to pull the data without having Pandas setting them to float64?

Thanks!

Comment: No. Question has been asked a bunch of times before. In Python, null representation comes from Numpy, and Numpy uses float to store null values (makes sense, if you read it up). So there is nothing that represents null in int. By the way, how does it matter int or float? They will both compute the same (in fact, precision will be better maintained in float).

Comment: Thanks @Kartik for the info. Those are keys from a left join and I want to use them to create a comma separated string in another query. I was baffled by it since I was coming from R and it doesn't do this cast when I run d `<- dbGetQuery(conPostgres, postgresQuery.sql)`

Comment: "By the way, how does it matter int or float? They will both compute the same (in fact, precision will be better maintained in float)."

float64 can only exactly represent integers up to 2^53

Answer (score 5):

As per the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na), the lack of NA representation in Numpy implies integer NA values can't be managed, so pandas promotes int columns into float.

Comment: Ahhh, sneaky. I was never aware of this. In light of this, I shall remove my suggestion to call `df.astype(np.int32)` in the above comment.